# Application deployed to Netlify unable to find files without .js extension

Tags: typescript, netlify

I am building an app with HTML, CSS (Tailwind), and TypeScript. I deploy the app on Netlify.

In my .ts files, I import modules like so:
`import { validateImage } from "../utils/validateImage";`
In my development environment, this works well. But as soon as the application is deployed to Netlify, I get errors from the server not finding the files in question. If I add the .js file extension, everything works:
`import { validateImage } from "../utils/validateImage.js";`

tsconfig.json:

```
{ "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "ES6",
    "outDir": "./public/js",
    "rootDir": "./src",

    "strict": true,

    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceRoot": "../src",
    "inlineSourceMap": true,

    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "exclude": ["**/*.test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts", "tests/"]
}
```

Does anyone know why this is?

I have tried different configurations in the tsconfig file, although I would expect any issues on this end to also be so in dev. So I suspect this has something to do with Netlify, but I can't find any information that helps me. Also posted it in the Netlify forum, but still no reply.

Comment: "If I add the .js file extension, everything works."  What does this mean?  You should also include the frameworks, build method, and how you're deploying to your post.  You should also be able to do a production instance locally with most frameworks which should reproduce the issue.

Comment: I updated my post to be clearer regarding the extension. No other frameworks or build methods used.